# Batch renaming files with a Hebrew letter followed by sequential number and not starting with 1

Tags: powershell, cmd, batch-rename

I have a couple of folders each containing up to 100 pdf files more or less.
For each folder I want to batch rename the files so that they will start with the Hebrew letter "ת" and then will have a sequential number. However, I don't want to start the numbering from 1.
For example:

```
pdfa will be ת20
pdfb will be ת21
pdfc will be ת22
and so on...
```

I tried looking at previous questions and coping the codes that were suggested there with the appropriate changes (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63161282/batch-rename-multiple-files-to-sequential-numbers) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers) but when running the codes on powershell it kept saying that either something in the command is missing or that something in the command is invalid (if needed, I can supply screenshots).

Codes I've tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set/a fileNum = 1
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  ren %%~nf%%~xf !fileNum!%%~xf
  set/a fileNum += 1
)
```

The powershell has said that `@echo off is an Unexpected token`, so I tried removing that line. It then said `The term 'setlocal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operatble program`.
After that notice it continued with `set/a` and said the same thing, and finally it showed the rest of the code and said it is missing and opening and closing.
I then tried running `ls -v | cat -n | while read n f; do mv -n "$f" "$n.pdf"; done`. I got the error `Missing statement body in do loop`.

It is important to notice that I have permission to reach these files only via my work computer which means that I'm not the admin and I cannot download new software.

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you require us to assist you to fix a problem with your code, we require at least a [mcve] of that code.

Comment: I apologize. I thought that sending the links to the posts from which I have copied the codes was enough. I've now edited the post to add code examples and the error messages I've gotten in return. @Compo

Answer (score 0):

The file is not in powershell language it is written for windows command console running as a bat or cmd file here is an example of it working at command prompt after adding in CHCP changes for Hebrew, but **note in my LTR explorer they show a different name order** compared to the command file sequence !

***I am sticking with mp4 as your code sample shows that not PDF*** but simply edit the batch file there  from `mp4` to `pdf`!

[image]

```
>REM lets add some files
>for /l %c in (1,1,5) do @echo file %c>file%c.mp4
>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 942F-936A
 Directory of C:\test

2023-05-09  14:17    <DIR>          .
2023-05-09  14:17    <DIR>          ..
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 file1.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 file2.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 file3.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 file4.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 file5.mp4

>REM lets rename using the batch file
>..\renumb
>echo off
Active code page: 65001
Active code page: 1255
>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 942F-936A

 Directory of C:\test

2023-05-09  14:19    <DIR>          .
2023-05-09  14:19    <DIR>          ..
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 20ת.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 9 21ת.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 22ת.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 23ת.mp4
2023-05-09  14:18                 8 24ת.mp4
              10 File(s)             81 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  756,414,377,984 bytes free
>
```

The mod needed is troublesome adding RTL characters so you may need to edit very carefully and alter the chcp values in a native Hebrew Windows MS Notepad. **I suggest you run `chcp` on its own at cmd window to check your own current default**, as I had to guess for English testing.

### renumb.bat

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set/a fileNum = 20
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  ren %%~nf%%~xf !fileNum!ת%%~xf
  set/a fileNum += 1
)
chcp 1255
```